# How to efficiently compare two objects and count the number of equal properties?

Tags: c#, list

I am working with two list that contain many properties. I am attempting to loop through the lists and return a comparison of the two objects in the form of a count (int). The count is defined as the number of properties that are equal.

Below is an example of this:

```
    class Object{
     public string prop1 {get;set;} //x5  Avg Length (20-30 Char)
     public double prop2 {get;set;} //x3

    }
    private int CompareProps(Object a, Object b)
    {
        int matchedElements = 0;
        if (a.Prop1 == b.Pro1)
            matchedElements++; ;
        if (a.Prop2 == b.Prop2)
            matchedElements++;

        // More Property Comparisons...

        return matchedElements;
    }
    ///Loops in another method with two Lists of Object, where each list.count = 300
        List1 = getList1Objects();//300 Objects
        List2 = getList2Objects();//300 Objects
        int l1 = List1.Count;
        int l2 = List2.Count;

        Parallel.For(0, l1, i =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < l2; j++)
            {
                int k =  CompareProps(List1[i], List2[j]);
            }
        });
```

This is very inefficient though. Is there are better way to do this in C#? The properties can be strings, doubles, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: It's O(1), so not inefficient at all. Cumbersome to write down, though ;)

Comment: @Adrian Thanks. For some reason the time to run this is roughly 2 minutes on a 300X300 list loop. If I turned these in to hashes or something would it be faster to compare. I think the string comparisons are killing this.

Comment: Did you comparing property type or property value?

Comment: How many properties to compare?

Comment: can you edit your post and show example of an object? with values

Comment: I have added an example of the class with the props and indicated the number of props with that type and the average length of the strings in them

Comment: @FrustratedEveryday i am comparing vals

Comment: You should post you loop(s).

Comment: Have added the loops with the compare method

Comment: That is just a lot of comparisons.  Don't think you can do better.  Since you are using i in the loop I don't even think you can use parallel.

Comment: The problem is not using generics at all (so no reuse of static used reclection) and CompareProps likely does not use reflection effectively (because of lack of generics). Result is super slow use of reflection which likely is obvious the moment you attach visual studio - namely the profiler.

Comment: @paparazzo you reminded me to add that the top loop is parallel. Thanks.

Comment: You want to compare all items of two list, To improve performance user async if operations are independent

Comment: All I can think of is running it through `Parallel.ForEach`.  It'll use more threads and completes sooner, though whether it's efficient or not is debatable

Comment: Instead of a comment //This is a Parallel Foreach post the actual code.

Comment: @paparazzo I've adjusted the code to show the actual. Thanks!

Comment: @paparazzo my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is really important, I think you need [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) since it uses HashSets.

```
private static int CompareProps(MyObject a, MyObject b)
{
     var aValues = a.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(a, null));
     var bValues = b.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(b, null));

     return aValues.Intersect(bValues).Count();
}
```

And here's the sample usage..

```
var a = new MyObject
{
   prop1 = "abc", // same value
   prop2 = "def",
   prop3 = 123,
   prop4 = 456 // same value
};

var b = new MyObject
{
   prop1 = "abc", // same value
   prop2 = "jkl",
   prop3 = 789,
   prop4 = 456 // same value
};

Console.WriteLine(CompareProps(a, b)); // output 2
```

**EDIT:**

Tested my solution by running 300X300 list loop.

```
private static void Run()
{
  var alist = new List<MyObject>();
  for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++)
  {
    alist.Add(new MyObject
    {
        prop1 = "abc",
        prop2 = RandomString(),
        prop3 = random.Next(),
        prop4 = 123
    });
  }

  var blist = new List<MyObject>();
  for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++)
  {
     blist.Add(new MyObject
     {
        prop1 = "abc",
        prop2 = RandomString(),
        prop3 = random.Next(),
        prop4 = 123
     });
  }

  var watch = new Stopwatch();
  watch.Start();

  Parallel.For(0, alist.Count, i =>
  {
     for (var j = 0; j < blist.Count; j++)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + CompareProps(alist[i], blist[j]));
     }
  });

  Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + "  seconds..");
}
```

> Result: 9.1703053  seconds..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can compare them like this:

```
private int CompareProps(Object a, Object b)
{
    int matchedElements = 0;
    var props = a.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach(var prop in props)
    {
        var vala = prop.GetValue(a);
        var valb = prop.GetValue(b);
        if(vala == valb)
            matchedElements++;

    // More Property Comparisons...
    return matchedElements;
}
```

It's easier to write and maintain for future changes in class properties. But be ware that it definitely takes more time. So it you are intending to compare hundreds of instances of objects this method is not recommended.

Comment: OP has already indicated that his design is inefficient and is looking for a better way than his 2 minute solution.   By that he means _faster_ not less code to write.

Comment: 2 min solution is not necessarily bad. and where did he mention Faster?

Comment: Like _7 Minute Abs_, people refer the 6 minute VHS version.  It's implied.  _"This is very inefficient though. Is there are better way to do this in C#?...For some reason the time to run this is roughly 2 minutes on a 300X300 list loop. If I turned these in to hashes or something would it be faster to compare. I think the string comparisons are killing this"_.  The part is in response to Adrian's comment

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `a` to `b` either by reference or hash for a quick short-circuit if there's a possibility of the same object occurring in both lists.

If the inner list is slow to create (e.g. a query from a DB) you can take a snapshot `.ToList()` outside of the loop if size/memory permits.

That's about it though.  Sometimes though, work is work.

Comment: If most objects differ, then it won't offer much benefit